# Recursion with AVL trees, function minimization

Tags: c, avl-tree

I have made these two functions that find if any AVL tree contains a string that starts with 'a':

```
int check2( int x, AVLNode T )
{
    if(x == 1)
        return 0;

    if( T != NULL )
    {
        x += check2( x, T->Right );
        if(T->Word[0] == 'a')
            x++;
        x += check2( x, T->Left );
    }
    return x;
}


int check( AVLNode T )
{
    return check2( 0, T );
}
```

where AVL is here

```
typedef struct node* AVLNode;

    struct node
    {
        char Word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
        AVLNode Left;
        AVLNode Right;
    };
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but I'm using `check(T);` only to call `check2(0, T);` and pass 0 to it, is there any way to use `check()` only, instead of calling a function that calls another function only to pass 0 initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because C dont have default arguments like in C++

```
int check2(AVLNode T, int x = 0)
{
//...
}
```

And not function overloading

```
int check2(int x, AVLNode T)
{
//...
}
int check2(AVLNode T)
{
  return check2(0, T)
}
```

You have two options: use C++ or use ugly define

Ugly define:

```
#define check2(n) check2(0, n)
int main() {
    AVLNode node;
    check2(node); // Expands to check2(0, node)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jacob!, that ugly define looks handsome in some cases.